# What is that tool called for scraping vegetables?

Tags: equipment

There is a specific kind of tool I want that is used to scrape the surface of vegetables in order to turn them into thin strands for spaghettifying or hash browns, but I don't know what it's called.

Comment: Could you please edit into your question anything you know about the tool, e.g. that it's forklike as you mentioned in comments below? It's hard for people to give you the answers you want without knowing those details.

Comment: Also: you kind of have to make up your mind, either you're open to suggestions for *better* tools for this (and don't need to tell people their answers aren't what you're looking for), or you're really set on finding this one specific tool, in which case that needs to be really clear in your question.

Comment: I've always use a simple vegetable peeler, I just press harder, works a treat!

Answer (score 4):

From your description, I think you are referring to a julienne vegetable peeler.

[image]
[image]

There are many different styles. Some may julienne on one side and peel on the other. Others may have interchangeable blades. And, as you can see in the lower picture, they can make different size cuts.

If you do a Google search, I'm sure you will be able to find one that will suit your needs.

Comment: That's definitely closer but the one I saw was more fork-like. What kind would be good for a semi-soft vegetable like squash or zucchini?

Comment: Really any of them should work well with any of the vegetables that would normally be julienned. For me the key is that the peeler is sharp. Just try to find one that will cut the size (diameter) that you want.

Comment: @Vane something like this?: https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/5157uU11hYL._SL1000_.jpg

Answer (score 3):

A spiralizer makes long strands, or a mandolin would also do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Would this kind of zester (eg: from Williams Sonoma) be what you're thinking of?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

For hash browns it is a grater.

[image: grater]

For spaghetti squash I just use a fork.